# XSLT Transformation with namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I need a simple xslt which takes input and gives the output as mentioned below.I have written a xslt but the namespace is getting ignored.Can you please help me with it.

Input message:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ns2:esbMessage xmlns:ns2="http://messagev2.esb.company.com/">
        <header>
            <identity/>
            <message-id>56b3b200-1945-44a9-9dcf-a90de1f99060</message-id>
            <correlation-id>56b3b200-1945-44a9-9dcf-a90de1f99060</correlation-id>
            <message-date-time>2016-11-14T11:31:49</message-date-time>
            <esb-environment>DEV</esb-environment>
        </header>
        <errors/>
        <body>
            <urn:submitOrder xmlns:urn="urn:switchyard-quickstart:bean-service:1.0">
                <order>
                    <orderId>100001</orderId>
                    <itemId>5001</itemId>
                    <quantity>5</quantity>
                </order>
            </urn:submitOrder>
        </body>
    </ns2:esbMessage>
```

Expected Output message:

```
    <urn:submitOrder xmlns:urn="urn:switchyard-quickstart:bean-service:1.0">
                <order>
                    <orderId>100001</orderId>
                    <itemId>5001</itemId>
                    <quantity>5</quantity>
                </order>
    </urn:submitOrder>
```

Actual Output message:

```
 <submitOrder>
                <order>
                      <orderId>100001</orderId>
                      <itemId>5001</itemId>
                      <quantity>5</quantity>
                </order>
   </submitOrder>
```

XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:for-each select="//body">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
                </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"  >
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to achieve the required result is:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:urn="urn:switchyard-quickstart:bean-service:1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="body/urn:submitOrder"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urn:submitOrder xmlns:urn="urn:switchyard-quickstart:bean-service:1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://messagev2.esb.company.com/">
  <order>
    <orderId>100001</orderId>
    <itemId>5001</itemId>
    <quantity>5</quantity>
  </order>
</urn:submitOrder>
```

contains a redundant `xmlns:ns2="http://messagev2.esb.company.com/"` namespace declaration which you should not worry about. In case it is important to remove it (though I don't see why), you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <urn:submitOrder xmlns:urn="urn:switchyard-quickstart:bean-service:1.0">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="body/urn:submitOrder/order"/>
    </urn:submitOrder>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

**I. changed XML**

```
<ns2:esbMessage xmlns:ns2="http://messagev2.esb.company.com/">
    <header>
        <identity/>
        <message-id>56b3b200-1945-44a9-9dcf-a90de1f99060</message-id>
        <correlation-id>56b3b200-1945-44a9-9dcf-a90de1f99060</correlation-id>
        <message-date-time>2016-11-14T11:31:49</message-date-time>
        <esb-environment>DEV</esb-environment>
    </header>
    <errors/>
    <body>
        <urn:submitOrder xmlns:urn="urn:switchyard-quickstart:bean-service:1.0">
            <!-- first -->
            <order>
                <orderId>100001</orderId>
                <itemId>5001</itemId>
                <quantity>5</quantity>
            </order>
            <?world?>
        </urn:submitOrder>
    </body>
</ns2:esbMessage>
```

**II. suggested XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns2="http://messagev2.esb.company.com/"
  xmlns:urn="urn:switchyard-quickstart:bean-service:1.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="ns2">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns2:esbMessage/body/urn:submitOrder"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**III. Result**

```
<urn:submitOrder xmlns:urn="urn:switchyard-quickstart:bean-service:1.0"
    xmlns:ns2="http://messagev2.esb.company.com/">
    <!-- first -->
    <order>
        <orderId>100001</orderId>
        <itemId>5001</itemId>
        <quantity>5</quantity>
    </order>
    <?world?>
</urn:submitOrder>
```

**Feedback to your xslt:**

You are removing the namespace of nodes and i think you don't understand what you did so far. `local-name()` returns only the name of a node. In your xslt you will create a new node with the local-name of the source node.

---

EDIT 1:

> Remove the ns2 from result

TBH with you, I don't know in depth why the above xslt copies the not used namespace to output xml. One solution would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:urn="urn:switchyard-quickstart:bean-service:1.0"
  xmlns:ns2="http://messagev2.esb.company.com/">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns2:esbMessage/body/urn:submitOrder"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi,I need to remove the namespace http://messagev2.esb.company.com/ and only have the namespace xmlns:urn="urn:switchyard-quickstart:bean-service:1.0" .

Comment: @user2761267 see EDIT 1 in answer.

Comment: "*I don't know in depth why the above xslt copies the not used namespace to output xml.*" Because `xsl:copy` copies all namespace nodes in scope.